# Шаблонизатор dle

Tags: шаблонизаторы, dle

Скажите простой пример использования на модуле шаблонизатор `dle`, просто не могу понять как использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте до полного понимания: [Общая информация по движку `DataLife Engine v.10.0`](http://dle-news.ru/extras/online/index.html).

> Многопользовательский новостной движок, обладающий большими функциональными возможностями. Движок предназначен, в первую очередь, для создания новостных блогов и сайтов с большим информационным контекстом. Однако он имеет большое количество настроек, которые позволяют использовать его практически для любых целей.